# Como pasar un parámetro o variable de un formulario Web a un .exe de Windows Form (C#)

Tags: c#, windows-forms, web

He desarrollado una pequeña aplicación con C#, que es un .exe, los usuarios deben registrarse y proceder a descargarlo, mi problema, es que necesito pasar de algún modo, un email a ese .exe, sin necesidad de que se registren en el formulario del .exe, ya intente con leer una Cookie, pero es un problema leer las cookies correctamente y más cuando usan distintos navegadores.
Mi pregunta clave sería ¿Cómo puedo comunicar mi aplicación .exe con el navegador, si es posible en tiempo real, para que sepa el .exe cual es el usuario que esta corriendo dicho proceso?

Comment: Normalmente se hace por medio de un campo en la base de datos.

Comment: ¿Podrías mencionar un ejemplo? En ese caso, como sabría la aplicación de escritorio que dicho usuario fue quien esta lanzando la petición.

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo veo de dos maneras, dependiendo de en qué momento necesitas obtener el dato.

En el caso de que sea necesario solo una vez, por ejemplo solo después de instalarlo, yo crearía un archivo para descargar que contenga un código que tu exe obligue al usuario a cargar. El archivo puede ser lo que tú quieras: `.ini`, `.dat`, o hasta tu propia extensión; lo importante es que puedas leer el dato y hacer una validación.

- Por ejemplo, que el archivo contenga un [GUID](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.guid?view=net-6.0) y, en ese caso, que el programa consulte a una API de tu web y tener una relación entre el GUID y el usuario en tu base de datos.
- Que el archivo sea el nombre del usuario cifrado, y el programa lo descifre para obtener la información.

En ambos casos, deberías tener algún dato que valide el programa para saber que es un archivo auténtico.

---

Por otro lado, si necesitas forzosamente invocar el programa desde la página, lo que deberías hacer es editar el registro de Windows para que admita un protocolo (como el http) asociándolo a tu programa, y leyendo en consecuencia el parámetro que le pases desde el enlace en tu web.

Puedes consultar [aquí (en inglés)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964152/how-do-i-create-a-custom-protocol-and-map-it-to-an-application) qué necesitas editar en el registro para lograrlo, [aquí (en inglés)](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/f9f215/windows-registry/) cómo lo puedes editar desde tu programa y con esta línea

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;
```

puedes obtener la ubicación de tu ejecutable para escribir en el registro la ruta final de tu programa.

En este caso, el código de tu programa podría quedar algo así (con `using Microsoft.Win32;`):

```
private static bool CheckKey()
{
    var result = false;
    var key = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey("MyExe"); // Nombre del protocolo, en este caso "MyExe"
    if (key is RegistryKey)
    {
        if (key.GetValueNames().Contains("URL Protocol"))
        {
            key.Close();
            key = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey("MyExe\\shell\\open\\command");
            if (key is RegistryKey)
            {
                result = true;
                key.Close();
            }
        }   
    }

    return result;
}

private static void WriteKey()
{
    var key = Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey("MyExe"); // Nombre del protocolo
    key.SetValue("URL Protocol", "", RegistryValueKind.String);
    key = key.CreateSubKey("shell\\open\\command");
    key.SetValue("", System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location + " %1");
    key.Close();
}
```

Y así crear tu clave en el registro (ejecutando el programa con privilegios de administrador, claro):

```
if (!CheckKey())
{
    WriteKey();
}
```

Con esto, puedes crear un enlace desde tu web en donde el destino sea tu protocolo personalizado y usar el argumento que quieras, por ejemplo el correo de tu usuario:

```
<a href="myexe:user@domain.com">Abrir programa</a>
```

y en el programa, en tu punto de entrada (el `Main`) puedes leer el dato así:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("args: ");
    if (args.Length > 0)
        foreach (string a in args)
            Console.WriteLine("> " + a);
    else
        Console.WriteLine("None :(");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
/*
 * Salida esperada:
args:
> myexe:user@domain.com
 */
```

Y con eso puedes comunicar de cierta manera tu web con tu ejecutable.